# Extending std::(w)string, by adding a constructor and some member functions

Tags: c++, string, inheritance, c++11

Sure, the `std::string` interface is already bloated. But it's missing some (for me) crucial elements. For example, a `std::wstring` cannot be constructed from a plain `const char*` (which is what is needed to create one from a string literal). I'd also like to add an  `operator/` and a `split` function. Anyways, that's all besides the point of the question. Which is preventing me writing a core class's guts for a project.

I know I can privately inherit from `std::(w)string`, and "import" all members with `using`. This misses the crucial non-member template functions, which are numerous.

How can I approach this better? I know public inheritance "solves" the problem, but it introduces the problems of `delete`ing a base class pointer of a class without a virtual destructor. Note that I'm not planning to add data members, so is this really a problem, or is this corner case still fine to use public inheritance?

Please don't say "don't do this", unless you can provide a way that 1) does what I want, 2) doesn't require me to write it all myself, 3) does not bloat my caller-side interface.

Comment: *"(which is what is needed to create one from a string literal)"* What about *wide* string literals?

Comment: To first order, `std::wstring` shouldn't be used at all; to second order, what's wrong with writing '`std::wstring foo(L"foo")`'?  Your `split` and `operator/` (what does it even mean to divide strings?!) can perfectly well be free functions, can't they?

Comment: @DyP: I don't care about those. Just plain text string literals in any place you'd normally use them. I want to use `wstring` on Windows and `string` everywhere else, but I want to use standard interfaces, so no special `tcout` and `tchar`. It's very much possible, there's enough typedefs to hide the underlying type's real name.

Comment: You should instead use `string` (containing UTF-8) everywhere *including* Windows, converting to "wide"ness *only* to pass directly to or from Win32 API functions that require it.

Comment: @rubenvb: That's not gonna happen (and really the wrong approach). You need to pick one encoding, like UTF-8 or UTF-16, and use it everywhere on all platforms, and then convert in/out of OS APIs on the platforms where they don't match. The existing design simply doesn't really support what you want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not derive from `std::basic_string<...>` but rather create algorithms doing the appropriate operations, e.g.:

```
template <typename cT>
std::basic_string<cT> construct(char const* str) {
    // ...
}
```

Likewise for `split()`, `operator/()`, etc. In principle, most members of `std::basic_string<...>` shouldn't be members in the first place...

Comment: I stress that I do not want to bloat my caller-side interface. This is terrible in that respect. I agree it's better design-wise, but it'll produce a lot of wrapper code... I added this as point 3.

Comment: @rubenvb: I disagree. Member functions for anything but non-crucial object maintenance is plain wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why free functions of the form `vector<string> split(string const& text, const char *separator)` would "bloat your caller-side interface" any more than hypothetical new `string` members would.  You've already been told what to do about constructing `wstring` from `const char *` (i.e. "don't").